# How can I get my PdfPTable's border and background color to display (iTextSharp)?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, pdfptable

As you can see, I've got a table which sports borders and a background color (Section 1):

[image]

...but section 3 lacks these sartorial refinements, and I don't know why.

Here is the pertinent code for section 1 (which displays as it should):

```
PdfPTable tblHeadings = new PdfPTable(3);
tblHeadings.WidthPercentage = 100;
tblHeadings.SpacingBefore = 10f;
float[] headingRowWidths = new float[] { 550f, 50f, 400f };
tblHeadings.SetWidths(headingRowWidths);
tblHeadings.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

Phrase phrasesec1Heading = new Phrase("Section 1: Payment Information", timesRoman9BoldFont);
PdfPCell cellSec1Heading GetCellForBorderedTable(phrasesec1Heading, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, ucscgold);
tblHeadings.AddCell(cellSec1Heading);
. . .
doc.Add(tblHeadings);
```

...and here for section 3 (which *doesn't* display as it should):

```
// Section 3
PdfPTable tblSection3 = new PdfPTable(1);
tblSection3.WidthPercentage = 100;
tblSection3.SpacingBefore = 10f;
//tblSection3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

Chunk sec3PayeeStatus = new Chunk("Section 3: Payee Status", timesRoman9BoldFont);
Chunk requiredFields = new Chunk("    * Required Fields", timesRoman9BoldRedFont);
Paragraph parSection3 = new Paragraph();
parSection3.Add(sec3PayeeStatus);
parSection3.Add(requiredFields);
//Phrase phrasesec1Heading = new Phrase("Section 1: Payment Information", timesRoman9BoldFont);
PdfPCell cellSec3Heading = GetCellForBorderedTable(parSection3, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, ucscgold);
tblSection3.AddCell(cellSec3Heading);

doc.Add(parSection3);
```

What am I missing or forgetting? The difference in the table creation and setup is in the number of cells/columns, and related declaration (float array) and property (setWidths()). The code adding to the PdfPCell differs in that a Phrase 
is used for Section 1 (which displays as I want it to), and a Paragraph is used for section 3 (which doesn't), but I tried that:

```
// try using a Phrase instead of a Paragraph
Chunk sec3PayeeStatus = new Chunk("Section 3 PayeeStatus", 
    timesRoman9BoldFont);
Chunk requiredFields = new Chunk("    * Require Fields", 
    timesRoman9BoldRedFont);
Phrase phraseSection3 = new Phrase();
phraseSection3.Add(sec3PayeeStatus);
phraseSection3.Add(requiredFields);
PdfPCell cellSec3Heading GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseSection3, 
    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, ucscgold);
tblSection3.AddCell(cellSec3Heading);
doc.Add(phraseSection3);
```

...but that did no better, in fact was a little worse, because the "SpacingBefore" didn't seem to "take"

Finally (so far), I tried using Phrases instead of Chunks, like so:

```
Phrase sec3PayeeStatus = new Phrase("Section 3: Payee Status", timesRoman9BoldFont);
Phrase requiredFields = new Phrase("    * Required Fields", timesRoman9BoldRedFont);
Paragraph parSection3 = new Paragraph();
parSection3.Add(sec3PayeeStatus);
parSection3.Add(requiredFields);
PdfPCell cellSec3Heading = GetCellForBorderedTable(parSection3, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, ucscgold);
tblSection3.AddCell(cellSec3Heading);
doc.Add(parSection3);
```

...but that is no better, worse, or different than the first attempt (at least I get the vertical space back, though, separating sections 2 and 3).

What do I have to do to display the cell borders and background color?

### UPDATE

Here's GetCellForBorderedTable():

```
private static PdfPCell GetCellForBorderedTable(Phrase phrase, int align, BaseColor color)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = align;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 2f;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0f;
    cell.BackgroundColor = color;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'd start with the function `GetCellForBorderedTable` that appears to be taking a color

Comment: That function is used in the code that's working (it's used in both). I'll add that method to the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was (not "visible" to me until I compared the code in a code comparison utility, namely KDiff3) that I was adding the Paragraph, not the table, to the doc:

```
doc.Add(parSection3);
```

Now that I've changed that to:

```
doc.Add(tblSection3);
```

...it works.